# Suitable idiom or an expression

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, emotions

I want to describe a feeling of guilt yet relief. An example would be that a classmate is feeling reassured for thinking that his rival's marks are not greater than his but also feeling guilty for wishing bad.
I would be thankful if someone would point out an idiom or a proper expression for such a feeling.

Comment: I don't think "torn between" is an apt metaphor or name for feeling guilt and relief at the same time, because it can also be used for say "anger and amusement". Are there any German people here? They could give us a good word for this. They have given us "schadenfreude".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer this idiom

**Be torn between**

> To be or feel equally compelled to choose between two different people, things, or actions.

*John was torn between his loyalty to his friend and knowing he needed to report the crime to the police.*

[be torn between](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+torn+between)

In the above description one could say that "the classmate is *torn between joy and a sense of guilt.*

Comment: I think this suggests the "decision process" and I am looking for a reaction to an event. In the above example, that is the rival not getting higher marks than the person. Would this idiom work for the reaction?

Comment: I don't think it has to be that way. The idiom covers every sort of dilemma whether that arises from "decision process" or an instinctive reaction to events. The link I've shared also gives this interpretation of the idiom: _Be distracted by two conflicting choices, be in a dilemma._

Comment: Okay, thank you!